# How to combine Mac terminal find -name patterns?

Tags: bash, mac, xcode

I use Xcode. I want to use bash to batch modify the UI fonts.

Here is the code to "*.xib" and "*.storyboard":

```
xibd(){
     cd "$(dirname "$1")/.." && pwd
     find . -type f -name "*.xib"  -exec  sed -i '' s/'\<fontDescription key=\"fontDescription\" type=\"system\" pointSize=\"17\"\/\>'/'\<fontDescription key=\"fontDescription\" name=\"PingFangSC-Regular\" family=\"PingFang SC\" pointSize=\"12\"\/\>'/ {} +

     find . -type f -name "*.storyboard"  -exec  sed -i '' s/'\<fontDescription key=\"fontDescription\" type=\"system\" pointSize=\"17\"\/\>'/'\<fontDescription key=\"fontDescription\" name=\"PingFangSC-Regular\" family=\"PingFang SC\" pointSize=\"12\"\/\>'/ {} +

}
```

I want to combine -name "*.storyboard" and -name "*.xib", how to achieve it?

I tried

```
find . -type f -name '*.storyboard'  -o  -name  "*.xib"  -exec  sed -i '' s/'\<fontDescription key=\"fontDescription\" type=\"system\" pointSize=\"17\"\/\>'/'\<fontDescription key=\"fontDescription\" name=\"PingFangSC-Regular\" family=\"PingFang SC\" pointSize=\"12\"\/\>'/ {} +


find . -type f -name "*.xib|storyboard"  -exec  sed -i '' s/'\<fontDescription key=\"fontDescription\" type=\"system\" pointSize=\"17\"\/\>'/'\<fontDescription key=\"fontDescription\" name=\"PingFangSC-Regular\" family=\"PingFang SC\" pointSize=\"12\"\/\>'/ {} +
```

it does not work.

I have read the related of `man find`.  Still working on it.